# If animation is 40 frames, should I cut it off at 39?

Tags: animation, keyframes, frame-rate, loop

If I am making an animation loop that is 40 frames and I start it at 0, do I need to end it at 39 or 40 to make it loop right?

[image]

Another way to ask the question might be, does the last frame count as a frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes. Frame 40 does count as a frame, unless you specifically tell the timeline or NLA editor to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

If frame 40 smoothly leads into frame one, you should only need to render frames 1-40. Blender defaults it's render to start at 1. Basically if frame zero is the same  as 40 you can start your render at on frame one.